# Restore AWS Storage Gateway Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, files, gateway

I just setup an AWS File Storage Gateway server on-prem. I was able to connect it to an S3 bucket and I can mount it as an NFS share to Linux servers which is great. My concern though is this - if for some reason we experienced total loss of on-prem environment is it possible to spin up a new storage gateway server on prem and reconnect to the previous file share?

I'm assuming I could reassign the same IP and the S3 bucket would still exist with the data in there but I'm curious if any body has had an issue where the storage gateway server died/crashed and they had data in S3 and were able to reconnect and continue things as normal again.

Comment: I've removed the unnecessary bolding as it made your question difficult to read.

Comment: The easy way to answer your question is to turn your existing gateway off temporarily and set it up on another VM to see what happens. You might be better off creating a new test storage gateway rather than experimenting with your production data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All the data that has been synchronized to S3 will be available in a new gateway you setup and connect to that bucket.